# Smallest and Largest integers using if/else only

Tags: java, algorithm, if-statement

Here is my code to display smallest and largest integer by taking 5 inputs from user...it works for smallest values but not for largest and I cant figure out the problem...please help

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestAndSmallestIntegers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b,c,d,e;
        int small,large;

        System.out.println("Enter five integer values...");



        a=input.nextInt();

        small=a;
        large=a;

        b=input.nextInt();

        if (small<b)
        {
            large=b;
        }

        else 
        {
            small=b;
        }
        c=input.nextInt();

        if  (small<c)
        {
            large=c;
        }

        else
        {
            small=c;
        }

        d=input.nextInt();
        if (small<d)
        {
            large=d;
        }

        else
        {
            small=d;
        }
        e=input.nextInt();
        if (small<e)
        {
            large=e;
        }

        else
        {
            small=e;
        }


        input.close();  
         System.out.printf("%d is smallest and %d is largest", small,large);        

    }   
}
```

Comment: What are the symptoms/issues?

Comment: It doesn't prints the largest value right...whatever is the value of the fifth integer weather small or large it prints that...it works for smallest value though

Comment: You seem to think (judging by the logic of the program) that if for `A`, `B`, `C` such that `A > B` if `C > B` then `C > A`. It can be shown to be false, take `A = 10, B = 0, C = 5` for example. In other words a new value which is larger than the smallest one isn't necessary larger than the largest one.

Comment: This could be done much easier with a for loop, you should rethink your program with a `for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {...}` and 3 variables `input, small, large`

Comment: What should be the correct approach then

Comment: I am told to do it just using if/else

Comment: since you are reading input sequentially, you just need to keep track of the largest and the smallest number seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int a = input.nextInt(),
    b = input.nextInt(),
    c = input.nextInt(),
    d = input.nextInt(),
    e = input.nextInt();

private int small, large;

small = min(a,b);
small = min(small,c);
small = min(small,d);
small = min(small,e);

large = max(a,b);
large = max(large,c);
large = max(large,d);
large = max(large,e);

private int min(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) return a else return b;
}

private int max(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) return a else return b;
}
```

I think this works ;)

Comment: So Javascript (or whatever this is) syntax works for Java, too?

Comment: You are absolutely right, my bad. I thought you asked JS. I've now typed it in Java ;)

Comment: There's no reason to declared those vars/functions as `private`. Also, maybe use ternary instead of if: `return a < b ? a : b;` and `return a > b ? a : b;`

Comment: @mbomb007 Why make them public if no other classes are using them, although, both private and public are good options. And, yes, ternary is possible, but I personally prefer more readable code. Again, both are good options, depends on coding style.

Comment: I meant that no scope declaration for variables is necessary. They have a default, which is generally used unless you specifically need them declared with a different scope.

Comment: @mbomb007 True, but it is best practice to make variables `private` and `static` by default, and remove those modifiers if they cannot be used.

Comment: @mbomb007 `no scope declaration for variables is necessary` Oh please explain why it is *necessary*. And the package-private (or *default*) modifier should not be used as default for variables. This is mostly a very bad idea.

Comment: @TimVisser `it is best practice to make variables private and static by default` Its getting better :D. Can you explain why variables should be made `static` by default?

Comment: `private` for coding safety and `static` for runtime speed to clarify my comment.

Comment: @TimVisser I do not complain about `private`, that is ok, but the argument for static is not.

Comment: @Tom I think I do not know then. May I learn from you?

Comment: @TimVisser Do you know what `static` means? A `static` variable belongs to the class, that means every instance shares the same value for this variable. Where is the point in making variables `static` by default if they don't have the same meaning for every instance (and most of the variables don't have that)? And "performance"? I don't think that there is a noticeable improvement.

Comment: @Tom Ah, then we are on the same page. `static` does make runtime management easier for the JVM, thus making a slight performance improvement. So, when starting to declare a variable it is good style to begin with both `private` and `static` modifiers. When that variable cannot be `static`, as in many cases, remove the modifier. My point is that any variable that can be `static` should be `static` to improve overall performance.

Comment: @TimVisser No we are not on the same page. `static` variable should only be used if necessary. Not vice-versa. Writing every variable as `static` could be very error-prone is not worth this "performance improvement".

Answer (score 0):

> it works for smallest values but not for largest

As [lared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4248222/lared) pointed out, comparing against `small` to determine `large` is flawed. You must include something like this in your comparison logic:

```
    if (large < b)
    {
        large = b;
    }
```

in addition to your existing comparison:

```
    if (small > b)
    {
        small = b;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you always just check for the smallest value. you also need to check

```
if (small<e)
        {
            if(large < e)
              {
                  large=e;
               }
        }
```