# Does the Java static modifier have a positive effect on runtime performance?

Tags: java, performance, jvm

```
public class A {
    private int a;
    private static int b;

    public A(int num) {
        this.a = num;
        this.b = num;

        // which one is quickest?
        this.computeA();
        this.computeB();
    }

    public int computeA() {
        return this.a * this.a;
    }

    public static int computeB() {
        return b * b;
    }
}
```

In the code above, does the `static` modifier on the variable `b` and on the method `computeB()` have any positive performance effects on runtime on the JVM?

Comment: This line `this.b = num;` shows perfectly why I said it is a bad idea to decline the variable as `static` by default. For the other readers: [discussion in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850116/smallest-and-largest-integers-using-if-else-only#27850341)

Comment: @Tom I do not say I have another opinion. Trust me, when I developed for Android I have had tons of problems with 'carrying' `static` methods. But now I'm just plain wondering what `static` does with performance ;)

Comment: `static` is orthogonal to performance: use it if and only if it doesn't make sense for the static thing to be associated with instances of the class.

Comment: @Tom, you were more right than I am. Good discussion though!

Comment: @TimVisser "Good discussion" Indeed. I guess even if it is better for the performance, I would still prefer avoiding `static` variables if possible, because they might change the behaviour of other instances if changes accidently. But I guess you know that :D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like most of these questions you should consider clarity first, and performance a distant second.  Make the code clear and simple and it is likely to perform reasonably well.

In terms of clarity, the main advantage is making it clear you are not using `this` in the method.  This can make it easier to refactor the method.

As @OceanLife mentions, using mutable static fields should be avoided.  Static fields are like singletons, and they are harder to unit test and to make thread safe.

While I would make methods `static` where possible, I would avoid using `static` fields unless they are immutable.

using `static` on a method has two notional performance advantages

- it means one less object is passed on the stack.
- it can't be overridden so it is not "virtual"

In reality the JIT can optimise away most of the differences but since your code is being run enough to be optimised it can make a small difference.

BTW running your code enough to be optimised will make much, much more difference.

Comment: I particularly dislike the mantra of clarity before optimization. Surely, it is true, however, it is not the point of this question...

Comment: @Enerccio it is very rare that developers find a simple language feature which improves performance that the JIT hasn't already optimised. You have to really know what you are doing to out smart the JIT.

Comment: Sure, and I get that. However, I always feel like if someone asks for "Best apple pie recipe" and someone else comes with "Make this lemon pie because it is better". He asked whether x or y, the answer should be x or y or none or both but not "Why? Do this instead". But maybe I am just annoyed from irc channels where people question your motive more than your question...

Comment: @Enerccio I do try to answer the question literally but often on SO the OP  have headed down the wrong path which is why they got lost. Demeter (n) - a decision which is hard to make because so little depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't attempted any benchmarking of this scenario but use of the `static` keyboard (notably when developing with Java ME/Android) has a positive effect on performance. Some estimates discuss a 20% execution speed boost owing to inlining and the subsequent [re-JIT'ing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970015/java-calling-static-methods-vs-manual-inlining-performance-overhead) after the *so-called* 'warm-up' period.

That said, stateful static methods are bad. Recently, heavy weigh Google/Square devs have been discussing this with the [wider community](https://twitter.com/romainguy/status/551666650656030722).

Answer (score 0):

If you compare what [invokestatic](http://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--34.html) jvm instruction does compared to [invokevirtual](http://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--35.html) or [invokeinterface](http://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--32.html), you can see that invokestatic should be faster. Compared with invokevirtual, method is only looked up in the static method list (smaller) and class hierarchy is ignored. invokeinterface does even more work since it cannot optimize the method lookup (and thus is the slowest of them all).

Comment: While that's true in the simplest view of how those bytecodes operate, in practice the JVM extensively *de-virtualizes* methods, removing the differences. In practice, unless the method is actually overridden and the call is actually polymorphic at some particular site, the differences go away. Since the OP is comparing the two approaches, we could assume that the call is not going to be polymorphic or else the `static` approach wasn't viable in the first place.